Error al migrar el modelo de prisma con postgresql

Hola a todos, estaba viendo un curso de prisma con postgresql y queria poder migrar un modelo user para la base, pero cuando tiro el comando npx prisma migrate dev --name init, me tira este error que muestro en la consola, en la imagen de abajo. Queria saber que puedo hacer para arreglarlo

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

También me pasa, como parte de la búsqueda de la solución lo que hice fue crear el archivo de migración a mano, pero eso no soluciona el problema, por lo tanto ojala alguien sepa como hacerlo.
